# batch file to delete file contents after second occurrence of a tag

Tags: batch-file

Hello I am new to batch files.

I am working on a batch file to delete lines from an XML file, for example `C:\NewFile\ABC.xml`

Everything after second occurrence of a tag to its last occurrence should be deleted from file contents.

`ABC.xml` looks for example as follows:

```
tag1
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
/tag1
```

Desired output:

```
tag1
    tag2......some text....../tag2
    tag2......some text....../tag2
/tag1
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: I don't think you can get this work with standard batch functionality. You're looking at something equivalent to the *nix sed or awk. Powershell might have what you want, it's much more powerwall than batch/dos.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @SebastiaanMegens - You actually can probably do this in pure batch, you'd just have to have a counter variable and read in the entire file beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a powerful text editor with Perl regular expression Replace support like UltraEdit, Notepad++, Sublime Text, etc.

Run a Perl regular expression Replace All from top of file with

```
^((?:.*?tag2[\s\S]*?/tag2.*\r?\n){2})(?:.*?tag2[\s\S]*?/tag2.*\r?\n)+
```

as search string and `\1` as replace string.

Explanation:

`^` ... start search at beginning of a line.

`(`...`)` ... is a marking group. The string found by the expression inside this marking group can be back referenced in search or replace string. In this search string there is 1 marking group which is back referenced with `\1` in replace string to keep the first 2 `tag2` elements and delete all other.

`(?:`...`)` ... is a **non** marking group. A non marking group is often used for an OR expression or as here for this search string to apply a multiplier to an expression like `{2}` and `+`.

`.*?` ... find any character except newline characters 0 or more times non greedy. Non greedy means stop matching any characters except newline characters on first occurrence of next string which is fixed string `tag2`.

`[\s\S]*?` ... matches any whitespace character OR any non whitespace character 0 or more times non greedy. In other words `[\s\S]` matches also newline characters as `.` by default does not (except a special flag is used). The next fixed string to match is `/tag2`.

`.*` ... find any character except newline characters 0 or more times now greedy which means here up to end of line.

`\r?\n` ... match optionally a carriage return and a line-feed. So the XML file can be a DOS/Windows file with carriage return plus line-feed or Unix file with only line-feed as line terminator.

`{2}` ... means that the expression in the non marking group must be applied exactly 2 times for a positive match. Those 2 "lines" with `tag2` ... `/tag2` are found by the expression in the marking group and therefore are simply kept on replace because of `\1` in the replace string.

The expression to match `tag2` ... `/tag2` is used once again in a non marking group with multiplier `+` which means 1 or more times. Everything found by this second part of the search string is removed on replace.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a utility or library that is designed to parse and manipulate xml.

In a pinch, you could use my [JREPL.BAT utility that is able to do sophisticated regular expression replacements](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). But regular expressions are really not good if you want a robust solution for xml processing.

[JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Your scenario is missing some key details.

- Is `<tag2>` always contained within `<tag1>`? or does the outer tag not matter?
- Should the counter be reset to zero upon each new outer tag?

First, I will assume you simply want to remove all `<tag2>` after the 2nd one, regardless where they appear.

I'll use your ABC.xml example from your [related SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/889857/109090)

***ABC.xml***

```
<tag1>
        <tag2>...... Once upon a midnight dreary, ......</tag2>
       <tag2>...... while I pondered, weak and weary, ......</tag2>
          <tag2>...... Over many a quaint and curious ......</tag2>
            <tag2>...... volume of forgotten lore— ......</tag2>
           <tag2>...... While I nodded, nearly napping, ......</tag2>
         <tag2>...... suddenly there came a tapping, ......</tag2>
                                ︙
</tag1>
```

The solution is fairly straight forward (Note - I am making lots of potentially unsafe assumptions about the layout of your xml documents. You are really better off using a tool designed specifically to process xml). I'm assuming you want to over-write the original file.

```
jrepl "<tag2>.*?</tag2>\s*" "++cnt>2?'':$0" /m /j /jbeg "cnt=0" /f ABC.xml /o -
```

- The `/F filename` option specifies the input file
- The `/O -` specifies that the output over-writes the original
- The `/M` option specifies multi-line mode which allow searches across line breaks, thus enabling me to remove entire lines.
- The `/J` option treats the replacement string as a JScript expression
- The `/JBEG` option initialises a `cnt` variable that is used to count the number of  tags found
- The search string matches an entire `<tag2>...</tag2>`, plus any trailing white space.
- The replacement expression increments the counter, and specifies an empty replacement string if it is greater than 2, otherwise the string is replaced with itself.

The output is

```
<tag1>
        <tag2>...... Once upon a midnight dreary, ......</tag2>
       <tag2>...... while I pondered, weak and weary, ......</tag2>

</tag1>
```

---

Now I'll make the problem a bit trickier. I'll add a second `<tag1>`, and assume you want the counter to reset to zero at the start of each `<tag1>`. I've also added another tag to show that it does not impact the  counter.

**XYZ.xml**

```
<tag1>
        <tag2>...... Once upon a midnight dreary, ......</tag2>
       <tag2>...... while I pondered, weak and weary, ......</tag2>
          <tag2>...... Over many a quaint and curious ......</tag2>
            <tag2>...... volume of forgotten lore— ......</tag2>
           <tag2>...... While I nodded, nearly napping, ......</tag2>
         <tag2>...... suddenly there came a tapping, ......</tag2>
                                ?
</tag1>
<tag1>
   <tag2>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>1</someOtherTag>
   <tag2>Humpty Dumpty had a great fall</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>2</someOtherTag>
   <tag2>All the king's horses, and all the king's men</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>3</someOtherTag>
   <tag2>Couldn't put Humpty together again</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>4</someOtherTag>
<tag1>
```

The solution is very similar, except now I use the `/T` option to specify space delimited lists of search and replace expressions. The first search expression matches `<tag1>`, and the replace value simply resets the counter to 0, without modifying the value. The 2nd search expression matches the entire `<tag2>...</tag2>` as before, and the replacement also functions as before. I'm assuming that `<tag1>` always precedes the first `<tag2>` so I don't have to worry about declaring and initializing the counter via `/JBEG`.

```
jrepl "<tag1> <tag2>.*?</tag2>\s*" "cnt=0;$0 ++cnt>2?'':$0" /t " " /m /j /f XYZ.xml /o -
```

Here is the output:

```
<tag1>
        <tag2>...... Once upon a midnight dreary, ......</tag2>
       <tag2>...... while I pondered, weak and weary, ......</tag2>
          ?
</tag1>
<tag1>
   <tag2>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>1</someOtherTag>
   <tag2>Humpty Dumpty had a great fall</tag2>
   <someOtherTag>2</someOtherTag>
   <someOtherTag>3</someOtherTag>
   <someOtherTag>4</someOtherTag>
<tag1>
```

Since JREPL is a batch file, you must precede the command with CALL if you want to use it within another batch script.

Use `JREPL /?` to get complete help on all the options available to JREPL.